# Using a condition after a subshell affects ERR_EXIT within it

Tags: shell, error-handling, zsh

Using a condition on a subshell affects error handling within it:

```
❯ zsh -fc '(
setopt ERR_EXIT

false
echo impossible
) || true
'
         
impossible
```

Why does this happen? How do I solve it?

I can work around it using  `; (( $? == 0 )) || failure-handler-command`, but I really don't like this behavior.

Comment: Please don't use the [tag:bash] tag for questions about other shells.

Comment: I can reproduce it. Interestingly, if we write it in a single line, `zsh -fc '(setopt ERR_EXIT; false; echo impossible)'`, nothing is printed.

Comment: What!?  A shell has unexpected behavior when ERR_EXIT is set?!  Surely that's not possible!!

Comment: Bottom line: ERR_EXIT and errexit and set -e and all of their derivatives have confusing edge cases that make shell scripts more confusing rather than less so.  Many allegedly knowledgable sources will claim that "best practice" is to enable that setting, but best practice is to ignore those sources.  Disable errexit.  If you want to abort a script when a comand fails, write `cmd || exit`.

Comment: It's not a zsh-specific source, but [BashFAQ #105](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Examples) has a number of examples of places where errexit makes shell behavior worse rather than better. https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/ has another comparison of `set -e` behaviors across historical shells and shell versions; you'll note that use of this flag makes your code far less portable, as it induces a number of unintuitive, undocumented, version-specific behaviors.

Comment: (removed the terminal tag because nothing about this is terminal-specific; you'd have the same behavior from a zsh interpreter with no terminal connected to it at all).

Comment: Note that `; (( $? == 0 )) || failure-handler-command` is more simply written `|| failure-handler-command`.  You almost never need to explicitly reference `$?`.

Answer (score 2):

"Why does this happen?"  Because historically errexit, ERR_EXIT, set -e, and all of its derivatives are fickle, poorly desiged, poorly implemented, and poorly conceived.  Stop using them.

What you are trying to do can be more easily achieved with something like:

```
$ zsh -fc '(          
trap failure-handler-cmd 0
false || exit
echo not reached
) || true
'
failed
```

(Here, `failure-handler-cmd` is just writing the string "failed")

In other words, instead of expecting the shell to terminate when `false` is executed, be explicit and tell the shell to terminate by writing `false || exit`.  This way, someone reading your code later will not have to wonder about the original author's expectation.  When I see `cmd1; cmd2; cmd3` and `cmd1` is sufficiently complex that the author may have expected it to fail, but `cmd2` is `cat intermediate-file`, I have to wonder if the author understood that failure of `cat` may cause the script to terminate, or if the author is even aware that errexit is in effect, or if they even thought about it at all.  Explicit is better than implicit.  Burninate all occurrences of `set -e` in your code base, and do it now.

Case in point: why is this script executing with `|| true` at the end?  I *suspect* this is because it is running in an environment in which some form of errexit is in effect and the author wants to prevent the parent shell from terminating if this sub-script fails.  The `|| true` idiom seems to exist only as a hacky work around to temporarily disable errexit, so we are being explicit about disabling the implicit, which suggests that the entire environment is fubar.  Although, in this case I suppose the `|| true` is here to demonstrate the odd behavior of the subshell's behavior, and is probably the root cause of the issue.  ERR_EXIT behavior within a `||` is counterintuitively propagating down into the subshell.  I don't know that is actually what's happening, and it doesn't really matter because the correct solution is to stop using errexit so you don't have to think about its behavior.

Comment: `|| true` is indeed only for reproduction. It was actually `|| bell-fail` which sends me a notification that things have failed. I guess I'll go back to my old practice of writing explicit `|| return $?`, LOL.